# Cómo unir los campos en la misma fila en esta consulta access y SQL?

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT p.nombre AS Proveedor, Sum(r.val_notacred) AS NotaCredito, Sum(r.total_remision) AS Total, Sum(r.val_notacred) AS SumaDeval_notacred, Sum(r.total_remision) AS SumaDetotal_remision, c.pagada
FROM compras AS c INNER JOIN (detalle_remisiones AS r INNER JOIN cat_proveedores AS p ON r.cve_proveedor = p.cve_prov) ON c.folio_compra = r.no_remision
WHERE (((r.cancelado)=0) AND ((r.fecha) Between [@FechaInicial] And [@FechaFinal]))
GROUP BY p.nombre, c.pagada
ORDER BY p.nombre, c.pagada;
```

Necesito que los campos que selecione se vean todos en la misma fila y me divide los pagados y no pagados en diferente fila, me gustaria que se visualizara asi:

```
val_cred total_remisiones  val_cred total_remisiones
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Me parece familiar la pregunta... Pon en el título el problema _específico_ que estás teniendo, y en el cuerpo el resultado esperado y el obtenido. Lee [ask]. Alguien que llegue a tener un problema similar no encontrará tu pregunta si se titula "¿qué está mal en esta consulta?".

Comment: ¡No vandalices tu pregunta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se si comprendo bien tu problema, estaría bueno ver el resultado que te da..

Por lo que entiendo te muestra 2 líneas con los totales para compras pagadas y no pagadas. Si quieres las 2 líneas "juntas" tendrías que quitar el c.pagada:

```
SELECT p.nombre              AS Proveedor,
       Sum(r.val_notacred)   AS NotaCredito,
       Sum(r.total_remision) AS Total,
       Sum(r.val_notacred)   AS SumaDeval_notacred,
       Sum(r.total_remision) AS SumaDetotal_remision,
FROM   compras AS c
       INNER JOIN (detalle_remisiones AS r
                   INNER JOIN cat_proveedores AS p
                           ON r.cve_proveedor = p.cve_prov)
               ON c.folio_compra = r.no_remision
WHERE  ( ( ( r.cancelado ) = 0 )
         AND ( ( r.fecha ) BETWEEN [@fechainicial] AND [@fechafinal] ) )
GROUP  BY p.nombre
ORDER  BY p.nombre
```

Comment: No conozco la estructura de tu base de datos, pero estas usando los 2 mismos campos para las columas 1, 2 y 3,4 (r.val_notacred y r.total_remision), sería lógico que te muestre los mismos datos

Comment: Es que utilizas los mismos campos, capaz es otro campo el que queres utilizar? o queres que en 1,2 salgan los pagados y en 3,4 los no pagados? disculpame, no logro comprender bien el objetivo de los campos.

Comment: En este momento no te puedo hacer la query, pero te dejo un link que te puede guiar a una respuesta, no se que motor de base de datos utilizas, puede ser que tengas que efectuar alguna búsqueda para asegurar la síntaxis.

Adentro del Sum() le podes poner una condicion sobre el c.pagada:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/0b407c3a-d217-4a69-a552-fca5e790aa40/sql-sum-con-condicion?forum=sqlserveres

Espero que te sirva!